# Sequence of transpositions that generates the set of permutations

Tags: permutations

So I *think* it's possible to create an infinite sequence of transpositions `T` = { `t`<sub>`i`</sub>, i ≥ 2 } satisfying ∀ `i` ∈ `[2,n!]`

- ∃ `a,b` ∈ `[1,n]` s.t. `t`<sub>i</sub> = `(a b)`
- `n!|(j - i)` ⇒ `t`<sub>`j`</sub> = `t`<sub>`i`</sub>

such that if you consider the sequence of permutations P<sub>n</sub> = { p<sub>i,n</sub>, i ∈ `[1,n!]` } defined by

- p<sub>1,n</sub> is the identity permutation
- p<sub>i+1,n</sub> = p<sub>i,n</sub> t<sub>i+1</sub>

that `P`<sub>n</sub> contains every permutation of `n` elements exactly once.

---

For example, if `T` starts with

```
{ (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (1 4),
  (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (2 4),
  (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (3 4),
  (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), (1 3), (1 2), ....
```

then `P`<sub>4</sub> is given by

```
{ (1 2 3 4), (2 1 3 4), (3 1 2 4), (1 3 2 4), (2 3 1 4), (3 2 1 4),
  (4 2 1 3), (2 4 1 3), (1 4 2 3), (4 1 2 3), (2 1 4 3), (1 2 4 3),
  (1 3 4 2), (3 1 4 2), (4 1 3 2), (1 4 3 2), (3 4 1 2), (4 3 1 2),
  (4 3 2 1), (3 4 2 1), (2 4 3 1), (4 2 3 1), (3 2 4 1), (2 3 4 1) }
```

and `P`<sub>4</sub> contains every permutation of 4 elements exactly once.

---

What I'd like to find is a constructive proof for the existence of `T`.
I'm sure I'm retreading old ground here, I just don't seem to be searching for the right terms to turn up what I'm looking for.

Comment: See for instance 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus-JohnsonTrotter_algorithm. 


Comment: @Richard Stanley: Thanks! The link you gave was broken, but it was enough for me to find [Wikipedia's page on the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).  If you'd like to upgrade your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: O.k., I will upgrade my comment. I am glad it helped. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter_algorithm.